# How to set flash message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newer in in CI and I want to set flash message on User login page If user Insert wrong username or password. I google it and found following code but no luck.

```
if($condition)
{
    $this->load->view('textbox');
}
else 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user', 'Invalid Username or Password');
    redirect(base_url('index.php/users'));
}
```

Have any configuration to set for display flash message. Required more information please comment. I will give more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CI Flashdata -**

1) Make sure you have loaded the **`session library`**. (you can `autoload` it in `config/autoload.php`)

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

2) To **`add`** flashdata.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

3) To **`read`** a flashdata.

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

4) To **`preserve`** flashdata for an additional request.

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

**In your case -**

**Controller:**

```
if($condition)
{
    $this->load->view('textbox');
}
else 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
    redirect(base_url('index.php/users'));
}
```

**View:**

```
if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('login_error')))
{
    echo $this->session->flashdata('login_error');
}
```

**Documentation:**

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html